# Errors plotting a trendline using matplotlib and numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

Edited to include full code and after attempting one solution:

I'm getting an error: UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype('float64') when following a tutorial to try and plot a trendline on a scatterplot I created, here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('dataSet.csv')

date = df['Date'].astype('datetime64')
actual = df['Actual'].astype('float64')

plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.scatter(date, actual, color='orange')

z = np.polyfit(date, actual, 1)
p = np.poly1d(z)

plt.plot(date, p(date), "r--")

plt.show()
```

if I replace the formula for z with:

```
z = np.polyfit(list(date), actual, 1)
```

it's a slightly different error, but still an error:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Timestamp' and 'float'

Comment: Please include a toy dataset that reproduces the problem. For a start - I don't see where in this code you plot the fit line.

Comment: How do I add the csv data here to make it most useful?

Comment: Upload it externally and post the link. Make sure it is publicly accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried this method with your dataset, and it worked:

```
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
plt.scatter(df["Date"]), df["Actual"])
```

Comment: I did attempt this solution, but unfortunately it just changed the error message

Comment: Instead of using `df['Date'].astype('datetime64')`, use `pd.to_datetime()` function. Then when you wanna give x and y to `plt.scatter`, change them to a list using `List()` function. I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: I just edited my answer, please check it out, and let me know how it works.

Comment: That still didn't work for me for plotting the trendline. The scatterplot hasn't been an issue, it's the trendline that is creating a problem.

Comment: Specifically this line: z = np.polyfit(date, actual, 1)

Comment: You should first change the `datetime` format to Tiemdelta, and then calculate the total seconds like below:
`x = x = pd.to_timedelta(df.Date).dt.total_seconds().astype(int) / 10**9
y = df["Actual"]
z = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
p = np.poly1d(z)
plt.scatter(x, df["Actual"])
plt.plot(x, p(x))`
Let me know how it works.

Comment: Okay I'll give that a try when I'm back home. So basically to get this to work I'll need to convert the normal date/time format to ordered integers/numbers?

Comment: Ok looks like that will work, looks like adding an index or 'period number' to the actual data would work as well (or period format YYYYMM - 202101). So I'm pretty new to python for data science - is it not possible to use dates without some sort of conversion to plot trendlines due to the formulas for the calculation? I would have to imagine there's something other than numpy that could be used for this process?

Either way thank you for your help!

Comment: I was I also wondering if there's a better solution for this. I hope you can resolve this issue in a better way. I'm curious about a better solution, Please let me know how it goes. And I'd appreciate if my solution was helpful, give me an upvote :)

Comment: Okay I may start adding some numbering system, I did upvote but it won't show up. Thanks again for your help.